# bash shell scripting,displaying output of menu driven program

Tags: linux, shell

I have a menu driven program in Linux shell scripting,I want to display the output of program in same console as the menu, and the output differs based on the option selected by user,how do I make the output and menu to b.e displayed in same console? 
E.g. 1) do this 
        2) do that 
When do this is selected,the action that happpens when it is selected needs to be shown on the same console as the menu appears.
For e.g. If the menu is on left part of console and option 1 is selected from menu :
   1) do this.                   Output of 1) must appear here
   2) do that.
you can say screen splitting.How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand you correctly. You could print the menu, read in the response and print the reaction.
Is it a menu like

```
(1) Do this
(2) Do that
(q) Exit

> q

Okay, bye!
```

? Please give an example!
Also, consider using e.g. [dialog](http://linuxgazette.net/101/sunil.html).
Hope that helps.